# Limit comparison test; is this proof correct, and can it be improved?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that $\forall n: 0< a_n, b_n$ and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac {a_n}{b_n}=c$ with $c \not = 0$. Then
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges $\iff$  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges

Suppose first that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ converges.

There exists an $N$ such that $\forall (n \ge N): \left|\dfrac {a_n}{b_n} -c \right|<1$, so $\forall (n \ge N): |a_n-cb_n|<b_n$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|a_k-cb_k|< \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}b_k$. Adding $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|cb_k|$ to both sides we get

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k < \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}b_k+\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}cb_k$. This shows that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, so $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges.

Now for the other direction of the implcation; we can simply use that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{a_n}= \dfrac 1c$ (which is OK since $c \not = 0$) and do the same proof.

Comment: It seems your proof assumes that $\lvert a_k - cb_k \rvert + \lvert cb_k \rvert = \lvert a_k \rvert$, which I don't believe is necessarily always true.

Comment: $a_k \leq (c+1)b_k$ for $k\geq N$, and now use summation. Everything is positive so there shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

In your proof, you took $\epsilon=1$.

If we take $\epsilon=\frac c2$,

For large $n$,

$$-\frac c2<\frac{a_n}{b_n}-c<\frac c2$$

thus

$$\frac c2b_n<a_n<\frac{3c}{2}b_n$$

and comparison test.

Comment: (+1) This is the typical way forward

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks and Happy New Year.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And Happy Holidays to you also.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Therefore $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|a_k-cb_k|< \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}b_k$.

I would use "$\le$" instead of "$<$" here.

> Adding $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|cb_k|$ to both sides we get $\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}a_k < \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}b_k+\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}cb_k$.

How? I assume that you use the triangle inequality
$$
a_k=(a_k-cb_k)+cb_k\leq |a_k-cb_k|+cb_k\leq b_k+cb_k.
$$

> Now for the other direction of the implcation; we can simply use that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{a_n}= \dfrac 1c$ (which is OK since $c \not = 0$) and do the same proof.

You don't need to "do the same proof". You only need to apply what you have shown to
$$
\tilde{a}_n=b_n,\quad \tilde{b}_n=a_n,\quad \tilde{c}=\frac1c.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take what you have and write it "backwards" for the sake of clarity.

Assume that $\sum b_n$ converges. Do your limit definition thing. Now note that:
$$
\sum a_k = \sum|a_k-cb_k+cb_k|\leq \sum|a_k-cb_k|+\sum|cb_k|\leq \sum b_k+\sum cb_k=(1+c)\sum b_k
$$
Thus, by direct comparison, $\sum a_k$ converges.